# How to raise an integer to fractional power efficiently?

Tags: python, optimization, pow, sqrt

I have an binary search implemented in python.
Now I want to check if element `math.floor(n ^ (1/p))` is in my binary search.
But p is a very, very large number. I wrote using `fractions module`:

```
binary_search.search(list,int (n**fractions.Fraction('1'+'/'+str(p))))
```

But I have an error `OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float`
How can I take to n to the power, which is a fraction and do it fast?

Comment: Have you tried a logarithm?

Comment: @ChrisJohnson You mean: n^(1/p) -> 1/p*log(n)? Or can you give a small example, because I am not sure if I good understand you

Comment: Sure, will post as an answer, hang on.

Comment: Actually I think Sean's answer is better; I withdraw my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your values of `n` are also incredibly large, `floor(n^(1/p))` is going to tend toward 1 for "very, very large" values of p.  Since you're only interested in the integer portion, you could get away with a simple loop   to test if 1^P, 2^p, 3^p and so on are greater than n.

Don't waste time finding exact values if you don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

`n^(1/p)=exp(ln(n)/p) ~~ 1+ln(n)/p` for big p values

So you can compare p with natural logarithm of n. If the ratio p/ln(n) >> 1 (much larger), then you can use approximation above (which tends to 1)